Is $\omega^+$ $\tau$-additive if $\omega$ is $\tau$-additive?
Let $\omega :\mathfrak{B}_X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a signed measure with $\mathfrak{B}_X$ being the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a Hausdorff space $X$. Suppose $\omega^+,\omega ^-:\mathfrak{B}_X\to \mathbb{R}$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\omega $.
My question is: Is $\omega^+$ $\tau$-additive if $\omega$ is $\tau$-additive?
We say that $\omega$ is regular if for any $B\in\mathfrak{B}_X$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a closed set $F\subseteq B$ such that $|\omega |(B\setminus F)<\varepsilon $.
We say that $\omega$ is $\tau$-additive if $\omega$ is regular and $\omega (\cup _{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda)=\lim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\omega (U_\lambda)$ for all non-decreasing net $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of open sets.

Below is what I tried.
Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$  a non-decreasing net of open sets with $(\Lambda,\preceq)$ begin a directed set. Denote $U:=\cup _{\lambda \in \Lambda }U_\lambda $.
Suppose that $\omega $ is $\tau$-additive.
Then there's $\lambda _0\in \Lambda$ such that $\omega (U\setminus U_\lambda )=|\omega (U)-\omega (U_\lambda )|<\varepsilon $ for all $\lambda\in \Lambda$ with $\lambda _0\preceq \lambda $.
Let $\lambda\in\Lambda$ be any element with $\lambda_0\preceq \lambda$.
To finish the proof I need to show that $\omega^+(U\setminus U_\lambda )<\varepsilon $ (or <$a\varepsilon $ with $a>0$ being a constant that doesn't depend on $\varepsilon $).
Since $\omega ^+(U\setminus U_\lambda )=\omega (U\setminus U_\lambda )+\omega ^-(U\setminus U_\lambda)$, I tried to prove that $\omega ^-$ is small using the regularity of $\omega$ but I failed.
